# g++ compiler not generating error/warning for undefined methods

Tags: c++, class, undefined-function

I have a class that has a declared method but not defined/used anywhere. I expected this piece of code to generate linking error but it did not. Looks like compiler is smart enough to remove dead code. Which default optimization is doing this? How can I explicitly disable it to generate the error?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
 int x;
 string name;
 void set(int val){ x = val;};
 int get(){ return x;}

 void Init();
};

int main() {
  Base base;
  base.set(10);
  cout << base.get() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT1**: Here Init() function is not defined and neither used anywhere. So, I expected compiler to complain about this not defined. But don't see any error/warning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What dead code? What is the issue here? Why do you expect the compiler to choke on that?

Comment: @curiousguy Added the details. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the linker will only produce errors for undefined symbols that are used. As you never call `Init` there is no error.

Comment: Is there a way, I can explicitly enable compiler to flag such issues?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, some compilers raise warnings for unused private methods but not for public ones

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like compiler is smart enough to remove dead code.

The compiler is not even "smart" here. There is no code using a function so that function is **not needed** to produce an executable program.

The function is not even "ODR used" so technically the compiler would be wrong to require a definition.